# Auto remove blank line in case last element is removed

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml to delete some values, it works fine unless if the deleted value is the last then it ends up deleting the blank line as well.

```
prefix_state:

  v4:    
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
          - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT

    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: True
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
          - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT
```

i read about inserting the comments to be added, but really not sure how to add it here.

The code used to remove the values in the yaml file is as below:

```py
yamldata=yaml.load(prefix_state_data,Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
for arg in argv:
  if arg is None:
    pass
  else:
    for i in yamldata['prefix_state']['v4']:
      if yamldata['prefix_state']['v4'][i]['community']['lb'] is not None:
        pass
      else:
        for j in yamldata ['prefix_state']['v4'][i]['community']['lb']:
          if argv[0] + '_NO_EXPORT' == j:
            lb= yamldata ['prefix_state']['v4'][i]['community']['lb']
            lb.remove(j)
```

Expected end result is as below:

```
prefix_state:

  v4:    
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
<<<BLANK LINE>>>
    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: True
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
<<<BLANK LINE>>>
```

Output because of the code:

```
prefix_state:

  v4:    
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: True
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
```

Comment: In this case the extra lines hinder readability because they interfere with your ability to recognize indentations as being the same (i.e. makes it more difficult than necessary  to see if `10.10.` indented the same as `8.8.` or as `v4:` and of course will force someone to scroll much earlier than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the data into `data` and then print out the comment attribute (`.ca`) on the
sequence using:

```
print(data['prefix_state']['v4']['8.8.8.8/32']['community']['lb'])
```

what you will see is:

```
Comment(comment=None,
  items={2: [CommentToken('\n\n', line: 12, col: 12), None, None, None]})
```

You see the comment is attached to the sequence for the second item,
that is on the last node before the occurence of a comment (empty
lines being handled as comments).  So if you delete the item created
for that node, your expectation should be that the comment associated
with that item gets removed as well.

Your code is incomplete, and it is unclear where `yamldata` and `argv` come from, but with 
your YAML in a file `input`.yaml` you can do

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
with open('input.yaml') as prefix_state_data:
     data = yaml.load(prefix_state_data)

lb = data['prefix_state']['v4']['8.8.8.8/32']['community']['lb']

for idx, j in enumerate(lb):
    idx_to_remove = []
    if 'BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT' == j:
        if idx > 0 and lb.ca.items.get(idx) is not None and lb.ca.items.get(idx-1) is None:
            lb.ca.items[idx-1] = lb.ca.items.pop(idx)
            idx_to_remove.append(idx)
    for idx in reversed(idx_to_remove):
        lb.pop(idx)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
prefix_state:

  v4:
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
      - dns
      community:
        lb:
        - SELF_NO_EXPORT
        - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT

    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: true
      tags:
      - local
      community:
        lb:
        - SELF_NO_EXPORT
        - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
        - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT
```

Things to note:

- Don't ever change the list that you are looping over with a `for`
  loop. That might work if it is the last element and the loop
  terminates, but you'll get incorrect results if not:

  ```
  a = [1, 2, 3]
  for x in a:
      print(x, a)
      a.remove(x)
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  1 [1, 2, 3]
  3 [2, 3]
  ```

  I hope it is clear why you need any found indices starting with the latest.
- I copy the comment of an element to be removed to the preceding element, if it exists
  and doesn't already have a comment.
- Alternatively  you can move the comment from the last sequence item, to the
  last key value pair of the parent collection using something like:

### community.ca.items['lb'] = commnity['lb']ca.items.pop(2) # make sure you calculate the 2 value

You can also add a comment to the last element of the list using:

```
lb = data['prefix_state']['v4']['8.8.8.8/32']['community']['lb']

lb.remove('BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT')
lb.yaml_add_eol_comment('\n\n', len(lb)-1)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

but that will insert an `#` before the comment, because it doesn't start with one and
it is not completely trivial to work around that.

Comment: Hi Anthon, Thank you for your response. I tried both the options as you rightly stated the yaml_add_eol puts a # value after the last value in the list. However, the enumerate option that you mentioned above works perfectly and gives the expected result. Thanks for your help on the same.